# How is this class connecting to the sound?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, audio, embed

im trying to use (well succeeding) to use this sound class

http://www.mcfunkypants.com/2011/as3-pitch-shift-mp3/

the example code looks like this. . .

```
public class Pitch_Shift_Example extends Sprite
    {

        [Embed(source='Pitch_Shift_Example.mp3')]
        private var engine_mp3 : Class;
        public var engine_loop:Pitch_Shift_MP3;

        public function Pitch_Shift_Example()
        {
            engine_loop = new Pitch_Shift_MP3(engine_mp3);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            var someText:TextField = new TextField();
            someText.x = 200;
            someText.y = 0;
            someText.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            someText.selectable = false;
            someText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            someText.text = "Pitch Shift MP3 Demo by Breakdance McFunkypants\nMove your mouse to change the sample rate. Enjoy!";
            addChild(someText);
        }

        private function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            engine_loop.rate = (mouseX / stage.width) * 2;
        }

    }
```

Now what is confusing me is how the engine_mp3 class uses the sound.

line one embeds the sound. 
line two creates an empty class called engine_mp3.
line 3 creates a new pitch shift class which in line 7 we pass the (empty) engine_mp3 class.

Basically how is engine_mp3 getting the mp3 data??

Any help is appreciated.

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like something like this:

You embed the mp3 file with these two lines:

```
Embed(source='Pitch_Shift_Example.mp3')]
private var engine_mp3 : Class;
```

Those two lines work together. The first line is embed *metadata* that describes the line below it. What it's doing is embedding the mp3 file and making it accessible as a class. You therefore have a reference to this embedded sound class with the variable name `engine_mp3`.

Later on in your code, you instantiate a new instance of the `Pitch_Shift_MP3` class, and you pass in the reference to your embedded sound class `engine_mp3`:

```
engine_loop = new Pitch_Shift_MP3(engine_mp3);
```

The constructor for the pitch shift class is expecting a class (that represents a sound) as its single argument. What it must be doing in its own code is instantiating the class that `engine_mp3` represents by doing this:

```
var instantiatedSound:Sound = new engine_mp3() as Sound;
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: ah, should have played around with the order of the code and i probably would have figured this out! Thanks for your explaination, it helps alot. :D